# Не добавляется новая форма в проект C# Visual Studio 19

Tags: winforms, visual-studio

Создаю небольшое Windows Forms приложение и необходимо добавить вторую форму, но почему то когда нажимаю на проект правой кнопкой мыши -> Добавить -> Форма Windows Forms, я не вижу в принципе пункта для создания формы (как я посмотрел в разных источниках, пункт должен называться Windows Forms). Мб я где то не там ищу, тк вариант с не установленными компонентами вероятно отпадает, поскольку проект с одной формой я смог создать. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что может быть не так? Если какой то информации не хватает, спрашивайте, дополню. Заранее спасибо!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы не устанавливали обновление?
У меня такая же проблема возникла после установки обновление.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена, всё таки не был установлен компонент "Разработка классических приложений .NET", только странно почему всё же проект WindowsForms создался